# Correct way of returning a task in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a scenario wherein I need to return a method that can be awaited from the caller.

I have here my implementations, and I just want to know which of which is the correct one.

Method 1.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Task MyTask { get; set; }
    public ClassA()
    {
       MyTask = MyAsyncMethod();
    }

    private async void MyAsyncMethod()
    {
       await LongProcessHere();
    }
}

public class MyCaller()
{
   private async void ExecuteAsync()
   {
      ClassA ca = new ClassA();
      await ca.MyTask;
   }
}
```

Method 2.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Task MyAsyncMethod()
    {
       return Task.Run(async()=>
       {
          await LongProcessHere();
       });
    }
}

public class MyCaller()
{
   private async void ExecuteAsync()
   {
      ClassA ca = new ClassA();
      await ca.MyAsyncMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: Neither are correct, because both use `async void`.  If your method is `async` then it should return a `Task` so it can be awaited.  `async void` exists only for backward compatibility with event handlers and should never be used outside of that.  (And used *very carefully* within that.)

Comment: A constructor should never start background work, so 1 is discarded. You should not wrap calls in Task.Run when you have no need, so 2 is also discarded.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto why is it bad to start background work in a constructor?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thanks for that. But, I guess my code above does not start a background thread in the constructor, it's just an assignment and will not run in the constructor. For method 2, if it's not the right one, so how would I return a task? All I know is to use Task.Run.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Because a constructor is only to ensure the correct data was passed in. No one can know if background work was started there and there is no way to gracefully handle errors in those background tasks

Comment: @user2964556 No, that's incorrect. Calling an asynchronous method will start the task

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it doesn't seem that bad to me. The background work started inside the constructor of the first example is represented by the public property `MyTask`. The client code can use this property to monitor the progress of the background work, and handle any errors may occur.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto unhandled exceptions are not deal breakers. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception#remarks): *To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on tasks, the .NET Framework 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved exceptions. Although unobserved exceptions still raise the UnobservedTaskException exception, the process does not terminate by default. Instead, the exception is handled by the runtime after the event is raised*.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are correct there. It has more to do with the fact that you wouldn't expect side effects from a constructor

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it is unexpected indeed, but I wouldn't go that far saying that it should never been done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking *should I expose a property or method*, then that entirely depends on what the `Task` represents.

If the task is something done once per instance of the class, then having a `Task` property is appropriate. Usually in this case, the property represents something about the instance, such as ["my initialization is complete"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) or ["I am done processing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.completion?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1#System_Threading_Channels_ChannelReader_1_Completion).

If the task is something that you need to do multiple times, then having a `Task`-returning method is appropriate.

`Task`-returning methods are vastly more common than `Task` properties.

On a side note, [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) and [don't use `Task.Run` unnecessarily](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html).

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would look like:

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    // always return a Task from an async method 
    public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
    {
        await LongProcessHere();
    }
}

public class MyCaller
{
   private async Task ExecuteAsync()
   {
      ClassA ca = new ClassA();
      await ca.MyAsyncMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: Does my code in method 2 is not right? It seems like the same with yours. Still I'm returning a Task in method 2, it's just that I have return a task.run inside to process the long running.

Comment: Is it really necessary for async/await in `MyAsyncMethod` how about just `return LongProcessHere();` ? I know if more code is later added, exception handling will be a factory, but if that is all the method is doing, I'm not sure that is needed.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen It depends on what actually goes on in `MyAsyncMethod`, we cannot know with only that mock call

Comment: what about inside the LongProcessHere method? for it to be awaitable isn't it that we need to call Task.Run to make it return a task?

Comment: @user2964556 Can you edit your question so know what is `LongProcessHere()`? We cannot be guessing

Comment: @user2964556 If `LongProcessHere` isn't awaitable then the code in the question, this answer, and Lasse's suggested change, wouldn't even compile.  Given that the code in the question presumably compiles, `LongProcessHere` is apparently awaitable.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use Task.Run to call an async method. Also async methods should have Task return type as opposed to void. And vice versa.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
    {
       return await LongProcessHere();
    }
}

public class MyCaller()
{
   private async Task ExecuteAsync()
   {
      ClassA ca = new ClassA();
      await ca.MyAsyncMethod();
   }
}
```